# How do I convert this .data file to a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get the dataset in pandas, but I'm not able already tried a few things with seperators and delimiters but sadly I didn't know how to continue.

Each row is basically converted to 10 row, but I want it back to 1 row with 75 attributes.

To demonstrate what I mean on the left what it is, and on the right its how I want it to be.

Is there someone who could help me out, would mean me a lot thanks!

[image: Excel]

The dataset I'm using can be found here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/
And then specifically the cleveland.data

[image: Jupyter notebook]

Comment: csv stands for comma separated values, so you should set your delimiters to ','

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832820/convert-data-from-data-file-to-csv-file-and-put-data-in-columns-using-pandas/47833036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to download a file from a folder containing a *WARNING* file, better is to read it. It says:

> The file cleveland.data has been unfortunately messed up when we lost
> node cip2 and loaded the file on node ics.  The file processed.cleveland.data
> seems to be in good shape and is useable (for the 14 attributes situation).
> I'll clean up cleveland.data as soon as possible.
>
> Bad news: my original copy of the database appears to be corrupted.
> I'll have to go back to the donor to get a new copy.
>
> David Aha

After carefully looking at the file, it contains sets of 10 lines, the last of each set ends in `name`. Each set should contain 76 fields. But only the 282 first sets are useable, the rest is messed up and cannot be used.

No possibility to directly use Pandas here, the file have to be pre-processed at Python level. Here is a possible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# Latin1 will allow to read even incorrect bytes
with open('cleveland.data', encoding='Latin1') as fd:
    # read all lines into an array
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fd]
# "group" them by 10 and split while we have 76 fields 
data = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: len(x) == 76,
                           (' '.join(lines[i:i+10]).split()
                            for i in range(0, len(lines), 10)))

# build the dataframe from that
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

It should give:

```
      0  1   2  3   4   5   6   7  8    9   ... 66 67 68 69 70 71 72  73  74    75
0      1  0  63  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  1  145  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
1      2  0  67  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  4  160  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
2      3  0  67  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  4  120  ...  2  2  1  1  1  7  3  -9  -9  name
3      4  0  37  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  3  130  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
4      6  0  41  0  -9  -9  -9  -9  2  130  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
..   ... ..  .. ..  ..  ..  ..  .. ..  ...  ... .. .. .. .. .. .. ..  ..  ..   ...
277  294  0  39  0  -9  -9  -9  -9  3  138  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  -9  -9  name
278  295  0  57  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  2  154  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
279  296  0  58  0  -9  -9  -9  -9  4  130  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
280  297  0  57  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  4  110  ...  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name
281  298  0  47  1  -9  -9  -9  -9  3  130  ...  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  -9  -9  name

[282 rows x 76 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily read with this way:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("processed.cleveland.data",header=None)
```

Result will be:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!
The problem is that this is already the processed dataset with only the 14 columns, I would like to have them with all the columns so 75.